# Redux handling domain specific actions in a global component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

My Redux app is broken down into individual components for the sake of modularity with the `app` domain being a kind of a shared infrastructure component which handles common ui changes like loading indicators.

```
app/ <- Global app  
---app_reducer.js  
---constants.js  
---actions.js
---...(react components)
users/
---users_reducer.js
---constansts.js
---actions.js
---...(react components)
products/
---products_reducer.js
---constants.js
---actions.js
---...(react components)
```

In my root reducer I use the `combineReducers` function to nicely split the state tree according to my domain:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import App from './app/app_reducer'
import Users from './users/users_reducers'
import Products from './products/products_reducers'

export default combineReducers({
  App,
  Users,
  Products
})
```

So my state tree looks like this:

```
{
   app: 
     isLoading: false,
   users:
     ['user1', 'user2', 'user3']
   products:
     ['product1', 'product2'],
     lastFetch: 1246578942621
}
```

Ok, so now I want to add some async functionality to `users` and `products` where they fetch data from the server. This is trivial using something like `redux-thunk` or a promise middleware.
So the action creator for `users/actions.js` might look like this:

```
import { LOAD_USERS_REQUEST, LOAD_USERS_SUCCESS } from './actions'

// Using redux-thunk
export function LoadUsers(){
  return function(dispatch){
     dispatch({type: LOAD_USERS_REQUEST})
     fetch('myserver.com/users')
     .then(function(data){
        dispatch({type: LOAD_USERS_SUCCESS, data })
     })
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that `products` might do something similar to fetch itself too.
Now, `usersReducer` handles these actions and sets different state props on the `users` subtree. Problem is, I would like to set a `loading: true` in the `app` subtree also so that my high level `app` component would render a nice loading indicator. But `usersReducer` doesn't get that *slice* of the state tree.

Without writing a custom `combineReducers` that will send all reducers the whole state tree what is the elegant way to implement this? I'm looking for a clean and scalable solution.
Here's a couple approaches I considered:

1)
Make `appReducer` respond to each new request.
This means that each time I create a new action type for fetch, I need to add it in `app/app_reducer.js`:

```
import * as productTypes from '../products/constants'
import * as userTypes from '../users/constants'

export default function(state = {}, action){
  switch(action.type){
    case productTypes.LOAD_USERS_REQUEST:
    case productTypes.LOAD_PRODUCTS_REQUEST:
      return({...state, isLoading: true});
    case productTypes.LOAD_USERS_SUCCESS:
    case productTypes.LOAD_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS:
      return({...state, isLoading: false})
    default:
      return(state);
  }
}
```

The problem with this is that I'll have to modify `appReducer` with each new action I create that requires a loading indicator.

2)
The second approach is to create two more actions called `startLoading` and `stopLoading` which will be invoked from the async action like so:

```
import { LOAD_USERS_REQUEST, LOAD_USERS_SUCCESS } from './actions'
import { START_LOADING, STOP_LOADING } from '../app/actions'    

export function LoadUsers(){
  return function(dispatch){
     dispatch({type: START_LOADING})
     dispatch({type: LOAD_USERS_REQUEST})
     fetch('myserver.com/users')
     .then(function(data){
        dispatch({type: STOP_LOADING})
        dispatch({type: LOAD_USERS_SUCCESS, data })
     })
  }
}
```

On first thought this seemed like a good idea but invoking 2 actions instead of one looks so wasteful.

I guess this is a common problem but I could not find any practical and "real life" suggestions out there.
I'd be happy to hear any other approaches to this problem or thoughts about the given suggestions.

Comment: If it was me, I'd take the second approach. It's a little extra boilerplate for your action creators, but I feel like it's cleaner than the alternative - your top-level reducer would get really long otherwise.

Comment: Yes but wouldn't you agree invoking two actions one after another (which would cause another state update) seems wasteful? It might not be _that_ bad but i'm afraid this kind of paradigm might cause even more sequential actions to be invoked.
i.e adding a START_PROFILING/STOP_PROFILING actions which render info to the UI while a fetch is running

Comment: Well, you're going to be causing two state updates either way - one in your `users` reducer, and one in the app reducer - so I doubt that it'll make much difference. I think the added clarity makes it worth it - that's completely a matter of taste, though!

Comment: @JoeClay As I understand all the reducers are combined together as the RootReducer. Every action dispatch call invokes this reducer once which in turn will call ALL it's sub reducers (which output the new state tree) and then re-renders all container elements that subscribed to the store passing the new state stree.
So if I call two dispatches one after the other, this cycle (rootReducer -> re-render) will happen twice.
Of course there are react's optimizations like the usage of shadow dom but it is still more wasteful then the first approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This topic is covered in the [Redux FAQ](http://redux.js.org/docs/FAQ.html#reducers-share-state). At the moment, yes, the answers are "write additional custom reducer logic", or "use `getState` to put more data into actions".

That said, there *is* a PR currently being discussed that would let `combineReducers` pass down the entire state as an additional argument.  See [Feature Request: Allow reducers to consult global state](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/pull/1768).

Also, to answer Pavel Tarno's comment: yes, each dispatch does call each sub-reducer function, *if* you're using `combineReducers` (see [Redux FAQ](https://redux.js.org/faq#performance-all-reducers) ); and yes, each dispatch will then invoke all subscribers; but the React Redux `connect()` function will only force re-renders for subscribed components which return modified/updated results from `mapStateToProps`.  Also, because of React's batching, even if multiple successive dispatches in an event cycle each caused a given component to need to re-render, there would probably only be one *actual* re-render.  (Finally, it's "virtual DOM", not "shadow DOM".)

Comment: I'm a little bit ashamed that I missed this really handy FAQ